# Cannot persist relations in Core Identity's ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I cannot find a way to properly extend ASP.NET Core's `IdentityUser` (after extending: `ApplicationUser`). I can override it and link it from other models, but cannot link from the user to other models. Simple data like `CustomTag` works.

Source code of the issue: https://github.com/chanibal/CoreIdentityIssue
Or, to be specific, [it's second commit that contains all the changes over the default template](https://github.com/chanibal/CoreIdentityIssue/commit/9f22b7c08a3e30e6b7b4c6465d761b0ae704e50f)

What I did:

1. Created new project:
   ASP.NET Core Web Application (Model-View-Controller)
   Authentication: Individual User Accounts, store user accounts in-app
   Updated the database
2. Changed the model overriding the `IdentityUser` (as in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)):

   ```cs
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
           {}

       public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
       public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; } //< doesn't help
   }

   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
       public string CustomTag { get; set; }   //< this works
       public Bar Bar { get; set; }            //< THIS DOES NOT WORK
   }

   public class Bar
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int Value { get; set; }
   }

   public class Foo
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }   //< this works
   }
   ```

   [image: ER diagram]

   And migrated the changes
3. I'm updating the Bar values this way:

```cs
    /// This should ensure a Bar is connected to a ApplicationUser
    /// and increment it's value
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IncrementBar()
    {
        // This DOES NOT work
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        if (user.Bar == null)   //< this is always null
        {
            user.Bar = new Bar() { Value = 0 };
            // _context.Add(user.Bar); //< doesn't help
        }
        user.Bar.Value++;
        // await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user); //<> doesn't help
        // await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);  //< doesn't help, starting to get desperate
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

The information is there in the database, accessible by SQL. 
But somehow it doesn't hydrate the `ApplicationUser` model:

[image: SQL dump]

Using Visual Studio 16.3.9

Comment: Added a minimal demo of the issue

Comment: How do the foreign keys look like in the generated database?

Comment: The foreign keys configuration is available from the [model snapshot](https://github.com/chanibal/CoreIdentityIssue/blob/master/Data/Migrations/ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs). But please note, that the question has been already answered. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF does not ever automatically load related entities. You must either eagerly or explicitly load the relationships. Eager loading is the preferred way, as it does joins to get all the data in a single query. However, `UserManager<TUser>` provides no way to eagerly load relationships. As such, you have two choices:

1. Explicitly load the relationship. This will require an extra query, though.

   ```
   var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
   await _context.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.Bar).LoadAsync();
   // note: for collection props, you'd use `Collection(x => x.CollectionProp).LoadAsync()` instead.
   ```
2. Query the user from the context by the user id, instead of using `UserManager<TUser>`:

   ```
   var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
   var user = await _context.Users.Include(x => x.Bar).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, both your solutions work. I was mislead, that EF does indeed load eagerly - because if it has data available, it links it despite not joining at SQL level, for example, having a user loaded via `UserManager` and then selecting `_context.Foos.ToArray()` (`Foo` has a `ApplicationUser` property), each Foo does have a `User` instance - because it was loaded before and is in some kind of cache.

Comment: You were not mislead. You misunderstood. EF does have an object cache, and it does automatically fix-up relationships when it has the data for those relationships in the object cache. That part is key, though. It has to already be there. If you query something later EF won't go back and alter entities you've already pulled out. Additionally, the context is scoped to the request, so you might have.queried something in a previous request, but that no longer exists

Comment: True. Thank you again for the help.